# Retaining the (curses-based) wifi network information from a Debian install

Tags: wifi, debian-installer

I ran my Debian install wirelessly.
I "just" selected wifi card, then ssid, encryption, password.
Then selected DHCP, not fixed addresses.

Network connected, then I finished the installation over the network.

After boot into the new system, I expected the network to be working over wifi, just as it is when I install over Ethernet -- the settings used during installation are the settings used in the running system.

Apparently it's not so with wifi; I have to fiddle with `wpa_supplicant` etc.
Is there a simple way to start wifi with the installer-used settings?

During install, /target/etc/network/interfaces contains:

```
# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug wlp4s0
iface wlp4s0 inet dhcp
# This is an autoconfigured IPv6 interface
iface wlp4s0 inet6 auto
    wpa-ssid MYSID
    wpa-psk  MYPASSWD
```

but after installation, it doesn't contain references to the wifi interface. I saved the file during installation, and used it after install. It works, but ...

- I get a link IPv6 after 30 sec
- I get a global IPv6 after 1 minute
- I get a DHCP IPv4 after 7 minutes.

If I remove the inet6 auto line from /etc/network/interfaces:

```
allow-hotplug wlp4s0
iface wlp4s0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid MYSSID
    wpa-psk  MYPASS
```

I get and IPv4 **AND** IPv6 so fast it is already ready if I log in as fast as possible after boot.

Comment: That’s odd, the settings should have been preserved. What does `/etc/network/interfaces` contain?

Comment: /etc/network/interface contain only lo and Source /etc/network/interfaces.d/ which is empty.

I didn't select graphical desktop, I only need a headless server, but I installed using the graphical installer.

I'll try reinstalling using the curses installer.

Comment: Well, 25% into a curses-based install /target/etc/network/interfaces contain the setup for the wifi. So I have saved a copy in case it gets overwritten.

Comment: It did get overwritten. So I copied the one used under install, and I then get a link local ipv6 after 30 sec, and a global after a minute. But getting a dhcp ipv4 takes 7 minutes! I'll edit the file into the question for formatting reasons.

Comment: As written elsewhere, the nmtui is not available after install. To get online to get a program to get online is a chicken-and-egg problem.

Comment: I have to type it manually, so I'll just say it's a Qualcom AR9285/Subsystem Azurewave AW-NE785. I don't have a rfkill command.

Comment: Why should I do that? Network is working, My main concern was that why did the network config from install not get transferred to installed serup.